# How to do azure authorization from mobile app to webpage

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-authentication

I used Azure auth login(AD B2C) in my app.After successful login i am getting accesstoken, Using this token, i am accessing api's.

In my app i have to open webpage which needs azure authentication. So without login how to access azure authenticated webpage from mobile app.

Comment: You have already logged in, why do you still need to login? You just need to use the token to accessing apis.

Comment: Here i am talking about webpage. In webpage how to bypass authentication